# Retain values from some pipes for final output

Tags: powershell, pipe

How do you do something like

```
PS> A | B | C | Format-Table PropertyFromA, PropertyFromB, PropertyFromC
```

So for example

```
gci -r -i *.txt | Get-Content | where {$_.Contains("SomeText")} | FormatTable -Property {$_.Directory, $.Name}
```

In this case gci output will have properties of Directory, Name but these will be lost when I pipe through Get-Content. How do I store this and make use later when piped to Format-Table. Can all this be achieved nicely in a single pipe chain command?

Comment: I dont know if it would be a perfect fit for this but if you dont want to use variables to store this and want it in one line then you could use [`Tee-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) i think as it can store data in a varialbe and sent it through the pipe. In your case `Add-Member` might be better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small modification to your command will work:

```
gci -r -i *.txt | ? { (gc $_.FullName) -Match "SomeText" } | FormatTable Directory,Name
```

Comment: This checks that the filename contains "Sometext". I was trying to say show me all .txt files, where the content of those files has "SomeText", and then display those files Name + Directory

Comment: Incorrect. `gc` gets the contents of the file and performs the match against that. The `$_.name` is the name of the file which is passed to the `Get-Content` command. No match is done against the filename itself.

Comment: How do you append inline $Directory"\" to $_.name when supplying to gc part?

Comment: `gc "$($_.Directory)\$($_.name)"`, but if you're doing that it's easier to use `$_.fullname`. Have updated to reflect this.

Comment: Legend that worked. How could I get the actual line that the text matched in the output also. So for example if I used the code above to search for the text "fox" in the following text. "I have a fox. It is red. I like my red fox" It would return sentence 1 and sentence 2 and list them underneat the Directory, Name of the file they were found in

Comment: You should ask a new question for this. Include the link here and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Arco444 has the right answer for this situation. On the off chance you are not showing us the real reason you are asking this question, or if others make their way here, I am going to show two examples that address this question as well.

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -filter *.txt | ForEach-Object{
   $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileData -Value (Get-Content $_.FullName) -PassThru
} | Where-Object{($_.Filedata).Contains("SomeText")} | 
Format-Table name,directory


Get-ChildItem -Recurse -filter *.txt | 
    Select Name,Directory,@{Label="FileData";Expression={Get-Content $_.FullName}} | 
    Where-Object{($_.Filedata).Contains("SomeText")} | 
    Format-Table name,directory
```

These "oneliners" are both examples that add a property to the objects created by `Get-ChildItem`. The new property `FileData` is then what you filter on. This logic can be applied in other ways as well.