# Retain values from some pipes for final output, followup

Tags: powershell, pipe

Re: [Retain values from some pipes for final output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902772/retain-values-from-some-pipes-for-final-output)

```
gci -r -i *.txt | ? { (gc $_.FullName) -Match "SomeText" } | FormatTable Directory,Name
```

I need to retain the output from `Get-Content` here to show the full line that it matched "SomeText". So if there are more than 1 instances I'd like them all listed below the Directory and Name for a given file.

So for example if I used the code above to search for the text "fox" in the following text. "I have a fox. It is red. I like my red fox" It would return sentence 1 and sentence 2 and list them underneath the Directory, Name of the file they were found in.

Comment: You should update your question with comments from Arco's answer in the previous. After reading that do I know what you want. Also `Select-String` would be want you want to use here

Answer (score 2):

If you were content with just the `filename` this should simply give you all the matches with the linenumbers and filenames and other details. If you need the directory as well you need to have a little more logic.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.txt | 
    select-string -Pattern "some" -AllMatches | 
    Format-Table FileName,Linenumber,matches,line
```

Something like this would include the same information as above but with the directory of the file that was matched. Might be an easier way but it does work

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Recurse -Include *.txt | ForEach-Object{
    $directory = $_.Directory
    $_ | select-string -Pattern "some" -AllMatches | Select-Object FileName,Linenumber,matches,line,@{Label="Directory";Expression={$directory}}
} | Format-Table
```

This is all based on the `Select-String` cmdlet which you could look up on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)

**Sample Output** (from second command with line matched removed as it takes up alot of space.)

```
Filename                      LineNumber Matches      Directory                                                   
--------                      ---------- -------      ---------                                                   
LICENSE.dom-documentation.txt         54 {some}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\ANav\web\WEB-INF\lib
LICENSE.js.txt                       372 {some}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\ANav\web\WEB-INF\lib
LICENSE.js.txt                       493 {SOME}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\ANav\web\WEB-INF\lib
README.txt                           310 {some}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\Jre                 
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt          203 {Some}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\Jre                 
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt          366 {some}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\Jre                 
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt          389 {some, some} C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\Jre                 
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt          408 {SOME}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\Jre                 
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt          630 {some}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\Jre                 
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt         1514 {some}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\Jre                 
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt         1689 {Some}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\Jre                 
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt         1705 {Some}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\Jre                 
RUNNING.txt                          171 {some}       C:\temp\Adoc72\ADOC N@vigator\NoInstall\Tomcat              
data.txt                               1 {some}       C:\temp                                                     
data.txt                               2 {some}       C:\temp                                                     
data.txt                               3 {some}       C:\temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
gci -r -i *.txt |
 select-string 'SomeText' -AllMatches |
 Group FileName |
 foreach {$_.Name;$_.Group.Line}
```